# UITextField always resignFirstResponder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I am using a UIPickerView and I want my keyboard to never show up for some of my UITextFields. When I call resignFirstResponder on the UITextField after it is touched it doesn't make the keyboard go down.

```
- (IBAction) txtFieldClicked:(id)sender {
[txtField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set text field delegate and implement its delegate methods

See [UItextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

If you dont want the keyboard to pop up, return NO for all those text fields here

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if([textField isEqualTo:self.myTextField]) {
return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you pratikshabhisikar. I appreciate another quick and correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

For each text field where you don't want to be able to show the keyboard, do:

```
[textField setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

You can also check a corresponding block in the Interface Builder UI. This prevents the text field from receiving the touch event that would otherwise trigger it to display the keyboard.

Comment: It turned our that I just needed to become the first responder and than resign it but your code would work as well.